# Munin plugins for Apache Solr 4.0+?

Tags: linux, tomcat, munin, solr

We have just started using Apache Solr 4.0.0 on Linux on a internal project, after having deployed Solr 1.4.1 and then 3.5.0 for a few years now.

From my searches, it would seem that most people are still using 3.x. In fact, all the munin plugins I can find (see list below) refer to an `/admin/stats.jsp` page that apparently, AFAIK, doesn't exist in Solr 4.0 anymore.

- http://rossduggan.ie/blog/technology/munin-plugins-for-solr/
- https://github.com/Gasol/munin-solr-plugins/
- https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/tree/master/plugins/solr
- ...

Later on I found this issue in the Solr bug tracker, [SOLR-1750](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1750), which seems to point to a snippet that you need to add this snippet into your `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<requestHandler
    name="/admin/stats" 
    class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SolrInfoMBeanHandler" />
```

However, trying to go to `/admin/mbeans` on my Solr 4 install gives me back some XML with information:

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="solr-mbeans">
    <lst name="CORE">
    <lst name="core">
    <str name="class">mycore</str>
    <str name="version">1.0</str>
    <str name="description">SolrCore</str>
    <str name="src">$URL: https://svn.apache.org/repos/...</str>
  </lst>

  ...

  <lst name="QUERYHANDLER">
    <lst name="/admin/system">
      <str name="class">org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SystemInfoHandler</str>
      <str name="version">4.0.0.2012.10.06.03.04.33</str>
      <str name="description">Get System Info</str>
      ...
  </lst>
```

But I still can't find anything related to statistics like queries or queries per second, used memory, etc... that **have to be somewhere**, since the web admin page clearly shows it.

I'll have to do more digging around in the Solr documentation, but maybe **someone out there knows and has already updated their Solr munin plugins for Solr 4.0**?

Answer (score 1):

`/admin/mbeans?stats=true` is what you want!

Comment: Thanks! I see now there's a `avgTimePerRequest` there, so I understand `?stats=true` does the trick. I will try to research some more to see if someone, somewhere has already gone through the work of writing (or changing) the munin plugins that can correctly expose this information. That's the only thing I need.